# Ubuntu 17.04 hibernate works but pm-hibernate does not

Tags: hibernate, 17.04

After installing 'hibernate'

```
sudo apt install hibernate
```

Hibernate works

```
sudo hibernate
```

But pm-hibernate does not

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

It blacks for a few second and is back on. After adding

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

to

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

The hibernate buttons do not work. Is it possible to modify their action to 'hibernate' or re-enable 'pm-hibernate'?

Comment: I had the same problem as you, and I followed this answer to enable the hibernation on ubuntu 17.04 . I had also to create the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and put in it `RESUME=UUID=swapfile_id` where the swap file id can be obtained with this command `sudo swaplabel /swapfile` . I also had to do modify the file `com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` like you did.

Comment: I asked almost the same question as you in here [https://askubuntu.com/questions/913517/cannot-hibernate-ubuntu-budgie-17-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913517/cannot-hibernate-ubuntu-budgie-17-04) , and I will give a complete answer tomorrow for others that are facing the same problem as us. (you can put the answer if you want, I will accept it).