# Cannot hibernate Ubuntu Budgie 17.04

Tags: swap, hibernate, ubuntu-budgie

I tried to hibernate ubuntu-budgie from the top panel, but it doesn't hibernate, it only locks the computer.

Seeing that, I tried to hibernate from the terminal using `sudo systemctl hibernate`, but I got the same result.

I used the command `systemctl status hibernate.target`, and I saw theses errors :

> systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Hibernate.
>   systemd[1]: hibernate.target: Job hibernate.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.

PS : This is a fresh installation of ubuntu budgie, and I have enough swap size (4Gb RAM and 4Gb swap).

PS2 : I am using a swap file and not a swap partition (That's how the new version of ubuntu creates by default)

Comment: 17.04 hibernate  issues should be covered by this answer.  Can you try please?  https://askubuntu.com/a/892410/14356

Comment: The `s2disk` command isn't working. it shows me that it is hibernating, but when I turn the computer on, it doesn't resume, it just do normal boot. May be because the file `/etc/initramfs-tool/conf.d/resume` is missing in my intsallation ?

Comment: It's working now when I created the file `/etc/initramfs-tool/conf.d/resume` and put in it `resume=UUID=my_swap_id`. I had also to follow this tutorial to allow hibernation from top panel buttons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@fossfreedom gave me a link to an answer, the answer is great, but didn't completely solve my problem. So I will put what I did to make my computer hibernate under ubuntu-budgie 17.04

## Create Swap File (go to the next step if you already have a swapfile)

These commands create a formatted 4GiB swap file, mounted and added to /etc/fstab:

```
sudo fallocate -l 4g /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo '/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

## Install Userspace Software Suspend (uswsusp)

```
sudo apt install uswsusp
```

## Verify Swap File Partition

```
sudo findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /swapfile
> /dev/sda1 11cc33ee-1234-abcd-1234-ddeeff112233
```

## Configure uswsusp

This will create /etc/uswsusp.conf and recreate initramfs using those details:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -pmedium uswsusp

- `Yes` to 'Continue without a valid swap space?' (Wizard hasn't set swap file yet.)
- Select the **partition** that the swap-file resides on, cross-reference with details from `findmnt` above. (Note: **not** the swap-file itself)

Create the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` if it doesn't exist, and put your swap_id in it like this :

```
sudo -s
swaplabel /swapfile
> UUID:  81bb07cd-d495-4733-be81-3447f9161f33
echo "RESUME=UUID=81bb07cd-d495-4733-be81-3447f9161f33" > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
update-initramfs -u
```

## Test Hibernate

```
sudo s2disk
```

## Use s2disk with systemd Hibernate

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

Edit the new file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service
```

Replace the last line of the file (starts ExecStart=...) with the following:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk 
ExceStart=run-parts -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

Update the systemd daemon and test hibernate:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

## Allow hibernation from top panel buttons

Open the file :

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

and find both sections :

- **[Disable hibernate by default in upower]**
- **[Disable hibernate by default in logind]**

and change both values from **no** to **yes** :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
swapoff /dev/drive/swap 
swapon -f /dev/drive/swap
```

Comment: Same result.
I did notice that I used to have a file called `/etc/initramfs-tools/config.d/resume` in ubuntu 16.04 , but this files doesn't exist in this installation ; could it be related to this problem somehow ?

Comment: Also, I just added it in my question : I am using a swap file and not a swap partition.